# SharePoint Online page version

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning, modern-experience, version-history

I can't find a versioning of the page. Is there an option for Office 365 SharePoint?

Cloud version.

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question? what exactly you want to get and from where?

Comment: I edited my page and all the text webparts are missing. I can't remember specifically what have I written down. I would like to revert page back to previous version

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to Site Pages library.
2. Select the ellipses( three vertical dots ) next to your page.
3. Select **Version history**.

By default Version history is enabled on Site Pages library. Make sure it is still enabled on it.

**To View/Restore/Delete Page from Version history**:

1. Hover on the Modified field and click on the small drop-down arrow inside it.
2. Select **View/Restore/Delete**.

[image]

Comment: Should this be done in Admin center? I can't find Site pages library

Comment: Where is your page stored? Which is the page you are editing?